# Error: no matching editors or conversion strategy found for XML to object conversion and vice vera

Tags: java, xml, spring, marshalling, unmarshalling

I am trying to convert xml to object and object to xml using marsheller. But I am getting the below error.

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'XMLConverter' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller' to required type 'javax.xml.bind.Marshaller' for property 'marshaller'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller] to required type [javax.xml.bind.Marshaller] for property 'marshaller': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Code Snippet:

App.java

```
 ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("App.xml");
            XMLConverter converter = (XMLConverter) appContext.getBean("XMLConverter");
Message message = new Message();
        List<HeaderPojo> headerList = new ArrayList<HeaderPojo>();
        List<InputInfoPojo> inputInfoList = new ArrayList<InputInfoPojo>();
        List<MessageBody> MessageBody = new ArrayList<MessageBody>();

        HeaderPojo Header = new HeaderPojo();

        Header.setMessageName("Hello");
        Header.setMessageDesc("hi");
        Header.setMessageType("Request");

        InputInfoPojo InputInfo = new InputInfoPojo();

        InputInfo.setProviderID("1234");
        InputInfo.setProviderLocation("1");
        InputInfo.setProviderRequestSource("sff");

        headerList.add(Header);
        inputInfoList.add(InputInfo);

        MessageBody Body = new MessageBody();
        Body.setInputInfo(inputInfoList);

        MessageBody.add(Body);

        message.setHeader(headerList);
        message.setBody(MessageBody);


            try {
                System.out.println("------- Object to XML -----------\n");
                JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Message.class);
                Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

                // output pretty printed
                jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

                jaxbMarshaller.marshal(message, System.out);

                System.out.println("\n------- XML to Object -----------\n");

                String xml = "<message><body><inputInfo><providerID>1234</providerID><Location>1</Location><providerRequestSource>sff</providerRequestSource></inputInfo></body><header><messageDesc>hello</messageDesc><messageName>FeeSchedules</messageName><messageType>Request</messageType></header></message>";
                StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
                Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                Message elementsOut = (Message) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
                System.out.println(elementsOut);

            } catch (JAXBException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }    
        }
```

xmlconverter.java:

```
private Marshaller marshaller;
    private Unmarshaller unmarshaller;

    public Marshaller getMarshaller() {
        return marshaller;
    }

    public void setMarshaller(Marshaller marshaller) {
        this.marshaller = marshaller;
    }

    public Unmarshaller getUnmarshaller() {
        return unmarshaller;
    }

    public void setUnmarshaller(Unmarshaller unmarshaller) {
        this.unmarshaller = unmarshaller;
    }

    public String convertFromObjectToXML(Object object)
            throws IOException {
        String xmlString = null;
        StringWriter strWriter = null;
        try {
            strWriter = new StringWriter();
            getMarshaller().marshal(object, new StreamResult(strWriter));
            xmlString = strWriter.toString(); 
        } finally {
            if (strWriter != null) {
                strWriter.close();
            }
        }
        return xmlString;
    }

    public Object convertFromXMLToObject(String xmlString) throws IOException {
        StringReader strReader = null;
        try {
             strReader = new StringReader(xmlString);
             return getUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new StreamSource(strReader));

        } finally {
            if (strReader != null) {
                strReader.close();
            }
        }


    }
```

app.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="XMLConverter" class="com.java.core.XMLConverter">
        <property name="marshaller" ref="castorMarshaller" />
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="castorMarshaller" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="castorMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller" >

    </bean>

</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
            <artifactId>castor</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Castor need this -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Please suggest me how to solve this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted the server and it started working. :)
This code works fine if someone wants to refer in future.